# XAML Binding - Cannot access array item

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm trying to bind a property via MVVM pattern.

The payload is something like that:

```
{
    "QualificationSummary": "For all positions individuals must have IT-related experience...",
    "PositionRemuneration": [
        {
            "MinimumRange": "62639.0",
            "MaximumRange": "137348.0",
            "RateIntervalCode": "PA"
        }
    ]
}
```

I Tried this, but did nor worked.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
       <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
           <Binding Path="PositionRemuneration[MinimumRange]"/>
           <Binding Path="PositionRemuneration[MaximumRange]"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Are you deserializing into a c# class?  Or are you trying to bind directly to a jobject?

Comment: @Jason, your question was essential to solve my problem. The problem was in the POCO class. That's the way I had to access the property:  <Binding Path="MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionLocation[0].LocationName"/> Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After spend some time understanding the problem, that's the solution.

The c# class:

```
public Positionlocation[] PositionLocation { get; set; }

 public class Positionlocation
    {
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountrySubDivisionCode { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

and to access the property:

```
<Binding Path="MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionLocation[0].LocationName"/>
```